# Hello MapView, moving a marker

Tags: android, overlay, android-mapview

I've been checking out **Hello MapView** at this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview), but it has been down for a couple of days now, so I will ask my question here:

I have added an overlayitem that looks like a marker. I would like to move the marker based on my updated position. Is there any way to target an existing marker and update the position, or do I need to remove it and redraw it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove and redraw in `onLocationChanged()` function, but the more efficient way is to use `MyLocationOverlay` as shown in this [example](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html#maps_mylocation).

Comment: Yes, thats what im using. But isnt there a way to move the marker by code? Do i have to redraw it?

Comment: **MyLocationOverlay** is automatically moved, but you need to move the map with it, not the marker (using `animateTo()` function)

Comment: Well ,its the marker that i want to move in this case, which is of type `ItemizedOverlay` if i recall correctly. Moving the map itself is not what im asking here. Sorry for beeing unclear

Comment: If you are using **ItermizedOverlay** you will have remove it from mapOverlays and redraw it when the location is changed.

Comment: Ok, and what would be the best way to remove the markers? I dont find any remove methods in itemizedoverlay

Comment: You will have to use `mapOverlays.clear();` this will remove all the markers, if you want to remove single marker you will have to use `mapOverlays.remove(itemizedOverlayInstance);`